Getting font name of font loaded with AddFontMemResourceEx winapi call
I'm writing a C++ app that uses AddFontMemResourceEx to load a new font. The problem is that to use it, I need to specify pszFaceName in the CreateFontA call. All of the resources I have read use a literal value like "YourFontName" as name, but the font is loaded by the user, so I need to get its name. Using the font file name is unreliable.
I have also tried to use EnumFontFamiliesEx: once before adding the font and once after, collecting results each time. However, it seems that the added font is not enumerable, cause collections are equal.
Maybe I have missed something? How can I get this name?

How are you loading the font file?

AddFontMemResourceEx() is meant for installing embedded fonts from inside your own app's memory, so you should know the names of the fonts you are embedding. For external files, you should be using AddFontResource/Ex() instead. But either way, if you read the docs for these functions, they explicitly say the installed font is not enumerable. And they don't return the font name. So, I think the only option is to parse the font file directly to extract the name.

wingdi.h has GetFontInfo

According to the Doc:AddFontMemResourceEx function A font that is added by AddFontMemResourceEx is always private to the process that made the call and is not enumerable.
